# vanishing locus of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I saw in somewhere that says $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^4$ with dimension $3$, which can be described as the vanishing locus of a linear equation $ax_1+bx_2+cx_3+dx_4=0$. Could someone explain what the "vanishing locus of a linear equation" is and how is that equivalent to $W$?

Comment: Vanishing locus of a linear equation sounds a lot like the kernel to me.

Comment: A linear equation $ax=b$ has a set of solutions which one could call the locus of the equation, in this case a hyperplane. Guess one could then call it the "*vanishing locus*" when $b=0$, and in that case it's a hyperplane through the origin, which is indeed a subspace of codimension $1$ (or dimension $3$). That said, I don't know how common such terminology is, unless it has been defined/used before in the context.

Comment: It might have started off as the "vanishing locus" the linear *expression* $ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 + dx_4$. Then someone confused the expression with the corresponding equation without realizing that including $= 0$ made "vanishing" redundant.